# Sharepoint Teamsite-calendar-webpart - save appointment to outlook

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, outlook, calendar

Is there a way to save a calendar entry by javascript to personal outlook-calendar within a sharepoint-calendar webpart ?

I want to save a created Entry in a sharepoint-calendar direkt to the personal outlook calendar of the user created it.

Any tip how to do this ?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Sharepoint 2019
vti_extenderversion:SR|16.0.0.19729

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is "kind of".

You technically don't have to write JavaScript to achieve this, as SharePoint has a built in service URL that will download an .ICS file to the user's machine, and whatever that user's default calendaring system (e.g. Outlook) will open that as a new Calendar item.

Although you can construct this link manually if you want to provide a calendar item download for one specific Event, you can certainly use JavaScript to dynamically fill in the parameter values in this URL, which may be easier that having to look up these values individually to manually construct a link.

The URL that you can provide a hyperlink to generate an .ics file is
`https://**SITE_URL**/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={**LIST_GUID**}&CacheControl=1&ID=**EVENT_ID**&Using=event.ics`

**SITE_URL** – The URL to the site where the calendar is hosted
**LIST_GUID** – The (guid) unique identifier of your calendar list
**EVENT_ID** – The (integer) ID of the calendar event

for example:

`https://mysharepointserver/sites/myteamsite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={B2E3EC57-9BA6-46A2-B072-578C9796A42E}&CacheControl=1&ID=26&Using=event.ics`

As an example of who you can use JavaScript to generate this link per event, the following code can be put in a Script Editor WebPart on the same page as a Calendar View Web Part, and it will insert a down arrow character in front of every event link that will trigger the .ics file for that event.  This script assumes you have the jQuery library already loaded on your page, and you will need to replace the string "NameOfYourEventsList" below with the actual title of your Events list.

```
function lookupListBeforeAppendingCalendarLink() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("NameOfYourEventsList");
    context.load(list, 'Id');

    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,listIdSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this,error));

}

function listIdSuccess() {
    var listId = list.get_id();
    appendAddToCalendarLink(listId);
}

function error(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function appendAddToCalendarLink(listId) {
    jQuery('.ms-acal-rootdiv .ms-acal-item').each(function () {
            var currentCalendarAnchor = jQuery('a', jQuery(this));
            var itemId = currentCalendarAnchor.attr('href').split('?ID=')[1];

            currentCalendarAnchor.before("<a href='" + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List=" + listId + "&CacheControl=1&ID=" + itemId + "&Using=event.ics'>&darr;</a>");
    });

}

function customizeCalendar() {
    //if you know the list id, you can hard code it here, 
    // otherwise use function to look it up first by List title
    // var listId = 'B2E3EC57-9BA6-46A2-B072-578C9796A42E'
    // appendAddToCalendarLink(listId);
    lookupListBeforeAppendingCalendarLink();
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(customizeCalendar, "sp.js")
```